# NoClassDefFoundError after adding test dependency

Tags: java, dependencies, noclassdeffounderror, hamcrest

I added hamcrest method in my wired tests and during build, it succeeded.

But when I tried to execute the tests, it threw the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/Matchers` error.

I tried adding the hamcerst dependency to the package pom as follows (even though the dependency was already there in the parent pom):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

But I'm still getting the same `NoClassDefFoundError` error during runtime. Why is it?

Comment: Do you run the tests within the IDE or with Maven?

Comment: @Marc with maven

Comment: How does your command line look like when you try to execute the tests?